# I don't understand why my code is looping when not supposed to

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

This is very simple, and I may look dumb, I'm completely new to Python

In my function user(), I put a while loop to see that only 1 word is entered and no numbers. Its a vowel counter that accepts 1 word

I don't understand why it keeps looping
I think continue means to skip all code ahead and go back to loop

Can someone please help me out

```
def user():
    global word
    while True:
        word = input(">")
        j = word.split(" ")
        if len(j) == 1:
            pass
        else:
            continue
        for _ in word:
            if _.isdigit():
                continue
            else:
                break
    return word

def vowel_check():
    global word
    word = word.lower()
    vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
    vowel_count = 0
    for i in vowel:
        if i in vowels:
            vowel_count += 1
        else:
            pass
    print(vowel_count)

user()
vowel_check()
```

Comment: I don't see anything here that could *stop* the `while True` loop.

Comment: `continue` and `break` only apply in the for loop here. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-break-statement - note "nearest enclosing loop".

Comment: Unfortunately, Python doesn't have labelled breaks or any other way of letting you return from an outer loop.  Just change your "break" to "return word" and everything should be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both keywords, `continue` and `break` only apply to the "nearest" loop. Here you will fall out of the `for`-loop, but are still kept in the `while`-loop forever.
To solve this, you could instead of doing break in the while loop just return the found value here.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using global variables and various pass/continue/break structures you can simplify the whole process as follows:

```
VOWELS = set('aeiouAEIOU')

def user():
    while True:
        word = input('> ')
        if len(word.split()) == 1: # exactly one word
            if not any(c.isdigit() for c in word):
                return word

def vowel_check(s):
    return sum(c in VOWELS for c in s)

print(vowel_check(user()))
```